# Use of web3.js batch requests

Tags: web3js, batch

The web3.js API allows for [synchronous RPC batch requests](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#batch-requests)
with the example given as:

```
var batch = web3.createBatch();
batch.add(web3.eth.getBalance.request(
    '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', 'latest', callback));
batch.add(web3.eth.contract(abi).at(address).balance.request(address, callback2));
batch.execute();
```

However when I try to implement it in my frontend like this:

```
var batch = web3.createBatch();
batch.add(currentK.claimFor.request(holderAddr.get(),{from:holderAddr.get(), gas:300000}));
batch.add(currentK.claimFor.request(to,{from:holderAddr.get(), gas:300000}));
batch.add(currentK.transfer.request(to, amount,{from:holderAddr.get(), gas:300000}));
batch.execute();
```

...where `claimFor` is an ABI function.  edit as ABI was incorrect<del>However it bombs out and the console presents an error message:</del>

The actual problem is that no activity is seen to be put against the blockchain.

--edit--

logging to console through a callbacks on the added functions returns the error:
`Error: invalid argument 0: cannot unmarshal non-string as hex data`.  In both `claimFor` and `transfer` the first arg is a string containing a valid address.

Comment: Is `transfer` actually a function? I don't think this is a problem with the batch, it looks like either `currentK.claimFor` or `currentK.transfer` is undefined

Comment: Perhaps, but clearly one or both of the functions is undefined in your code, so make sure your contract definitions are correct. I.e. check what `console.log(currentK.claimFor)` returns

Comment: Sorry my bad. Was using an obsolete ABI.  However with that corrected it's unmasked my original problem, in that no TX's are seen to be put against the chain.  Editing question..

Comment: Are your callbacks executed?

Comment: Yes, that's how I'm getting the error message

Comment: batch.execute() gives "(node:31377) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: method.callback is not a function" error. any help on this ?